# cgi-server : Automatically execute /index.sh?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

This is my Python script to listen to port 80 and serve a folder to port 80 like a web server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import BaseHTTPServer  
import CGIHTTPServer  
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting  
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer  
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler  
server_address = ("", 80)  
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]  

httpd = server(server_address, handler)  
httpd.serve_forever()
```

it works okay, but I would like it to automatically execute

```
  index.sh
```

if no file is specified. This is my `index.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "this is index page"
```

in other words if the url is `url/` then it should be considered `url/index.sh`

Comment: Why is stackoverflow turning my multi line codes into a single line ? it makes it difficult to see it all at once.

Comment: if you need to format code then use button `{}`. To get multiline in normal text you can add empty line between every two lines, or 3 spaces at the end of line before `ENTER`, or `<br>` between lines (no need `ENTER`).

Comment: use `import SimpleHTTPServer` and `print SimpleHTTPServer.__file__` to find source code `SimpleHTTPServer.py` and see how it works - it has hardcoded line `for index in "index.html", "index.htm":`. You will have to write own server and replace function `send_head()` which has this line.